# What's a word for "makes you feel like you're floating in the air"

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

I want to describe an orchestra performance that made me feel like I lifted up from the ground and *floated in the air* because it was so good. What's a good word for that?

I looked up [float](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/float) in a dictionary and found the following synonyms: *drift*, *glide*, *hang*, *hover*, *poise*, *ride*, *sail*, *swim*, *waft*, but none of them seem to really express what I felt.

Comment: buoyant, uplifting?

Comment: (To get further answers you need to explain why nothing you found in a thesaurus works for you.)

Comment: "elating" might work. Can you show how you would like to use it in a sentence?

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered.

Comment: *elevating*, *levitating*....

Comment: _Exhilarating_ is a word used with such a connotation though it does not literally mean "lifting".

Comment: `on the top of the world`, No?

Comment: Anti-gravity music?

Comment: I like the question, but users on EL&U are quick to close questions that show no research. I've provided a dictionary link, and argued that the synonyms don't really do the job. Please, please, please next time, before asking a new question just **show** and **share**  your research. And now I realise, I've probably wasted my breath on someone who is never going to come back... *sigh* ....

Comment: How about it made you feel "high"? As in it gave the same effect as taking hallucinatory drugs?

Comment: "LIghthearted" captures a bit of the feeling of floating.

Answer (score 5):

You are "**on cloud nine**."

> When one feels so happy, that there is a sense of weightlessness (like clouds).  Also, your sense of happiness is so high, that it's in the clouds.

From: [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/on-cloud-nine.html)

> Whenever a phrase includes a number, like the whole nine yards, at sixes and sevens etc., then attempts to find its derivation usually focus on the number. 'On cloud nine' is no exception. A commonly heard explanation is that the expression originated as one of the classifications of cloud which were defined by the US Weather Bureau in the 1950s, in which 'Cloud Nine' denotes the fluffy cumulonimbus type that are considered (very) attractive. Another explanation is that the phrase derives from Buddhism and that Cloud Nine is one of the stages of the progress to enlightenment of a Bodhisattva (one destined to become a Buddha).

Answer (score 3):

You felt

[***giddy***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/giddy)

> 1 a : dizzy
>
> b :  causing dizziness
>
> c :  whirling rapidly
>
> 2  a :  lightheartedly silly :  frivolous
>
> b :  joyfully elated :  euphoric

("Buoyant" and "elated," as suggested, also sound good.  "Elated" just focuses on the resulting feeling, and doesn't have anything to do with the floating aspect specifically, as far as I know.)

The performance was

[***exhilarating***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exhilarating)

> to exhilarate:
>
> 1
>   :  to make cheerful and excited :  enliven, elate
>
> 2
>   :  refresh, stimulate

"Uplifting" might work too, but be careful, because it can have a moralistic connotation as well.

Both words are from Merriam Webster.

The performance could be "buoyant" but it would mean something a little different.  It would be for a piece or interpretation that emphasized lightness (the opposite of weight).  You wouldn't be able to say this about a Brahms symphony, for example.  But it could work for, say, Paganini or Schubert or Mozart, I think.  If something is "sparkling," maybe it is also "buoyant."  But if something glories in its lower voices (e.g. bass, tuba) it probably wouldn't be buoyant.

Comment: P.S I quite like *elating* or *elated*, do you think that could work?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I think I would rather use "elated" to describe the feeling in the listener.  You found my typo, I think you should have the pleasure of fixing it!  What if I had just signed off (which I should have)?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - All the more reason!

Answer (score 1):

You might consider [*transport*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/transport), which can have the meaning of carrying away with emotion, exhilarate. As [*The Journal of the Music Academy, Madras*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-ZrjAAAAMAAJ&q=%22music%20transports%22&dq=%22music%20transports%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii2-2srM3RAhUCVyYKHR3nBckQ6AEIHDAA) (Vol 70) puts it --

> True music **transports** you to a new world of its own creation and in that world of music, you see a shrine of beauty which completely overwhelms you, transforming you into a totally different being.

Comment: Ah, the driveby downvoters strike again. Kindly have the courtesy to the OP (not to mention to me) to say why the answer is inapt. Otherwise you can leave the OP with the impression that a correct answer is wrong, or you can leave me with no opportunity to correct a wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm much for *elated*, even before reading the comments. Like buoyant, the literal meaning ("carried out") of the word fits nicely with the sentiment the OP wants to express.

Edit: After re-reading the question I realize that the OP is looking for a word describing a quality in the *performance,* not the *feeling* of being afloat that this performance caused in the listener. These two are closely related though — something that causes elation can surely be said to be ***elating.*** But that usage seems less common or idiomatic than *elated.*